# Creating geojson with lat lon out of shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have a shapefile which I want to export as geojson from qgis. To mix it with other data in my d3 project I want go get the coordinates als lat-lon-values (similar to the values you get by geocoding points with google-maps-API). Unfortunately qgis gives me x-y-values all the time like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Rettungsdienstbereiche-BW-RLP",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "GEN": "Name",
        "BEZ": "Class"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[393361.66645,
        5504072.61038],
        [393366.83389,
        5503968.65939],
        [393096.0904,
        5503949.01054],
        ...
```

I read many times that I have to give the layer a different CRS (e.g. EPSG 4326) but it does not seem to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to set a combination of CRS - the layer should be in the CRS that the shapefile is in, and when saving the layer as GeoJSON, you should set select EPSG:4326 as (output) CRS. QGIS will then do the transformation for you.

From the name of your layer, I guess that you should set your layer to be in EPSG:32632 (UTM zone 32N, for Rheinland-Pfalz). If you have a .prj-File included with your shapefile, the layer CRS should be set automatically.